# Push custom object and custom metadata type to scratch

Tags: salesforcedx, custom-object, sfdx-plugin, sfdx-error

So i retrieved custom metadata type and just custom object from my org via Ant Migration tool. After i createad a sfdx project. created scratch org and used push. It gives me error: 'Must specify a non-empty label for the CustomObject'. But there are label, plural label etc. What do i need to do?

Metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">  
    <label> Order</label>
    <pluralLabel>Orders</pluralLabel>
    <visibility>Public</visibility>
</CustomObject>
```

Ending is object-meta.xml

Comment: seems to be a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000KTo0QAG&title=must-specify-a-non-empty-label-for-the-customobject). Any reason for using the Ant Migration Tool to retrieve?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves what can i use? I tried illuminated cloud but same error.

Comment: Could it be the space between `<label>` and `Order`?

Comment: Don't use the mdapi if you can help it. `sfdx force:source:retrieve` would be ideal.

Comment: @Moonpie checked, but its was accidently added when copied here, sorry)

Comment: @sfdcfox tried too.

Comment: Is this a Custom Object or a Standard Object? (I know the terminology is confusing, that's just how the mdapi works)

Comment: @sfdcfox Custom

Answer (score 0):

Renamed file to object and back to object-meta.xml and it works. Dont know why cause it was 100% saved before.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this error when I was trying to use something like :

```
<nameField>
    <label>Progress Report  Name</label>
    <type>Text</type>
</nameField>
<pluralLabel>Progress Reports</pluralLabel>
<searchLayouts/>
<sharingModel>ReadWrite</sharingModel>
<visibility>Public</visibility>
```

and after checking the error and some workaround found that is suppose to look like some :

```
 **<label>Progress Report</label>** - Need to include this line to solve this error
 <nameField>
        <label>Progress Report  Name</label>
        <type>Text</type>
    </nameField>
    <pluralLabel>Progress Reports</pluralLabel>
    <searchLayouts/>
    <sharingModel>ReadWrite</sharingModel>
    <visibility>Public</visibility>
```